# redirect "www" url to "none-www" url (in folder)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My main site is running on `domain.com` with WordPress and already redirects `www.domain.com` to `domain.com`.

But I have a landing page with this url: `domain.com/design` (it's a folder on host). But this URL works for both:

- `www.domain.com/design`
- `domain.com/design`

I want it to redirect the first type to "none-www" URL.

I found this code but it redirects from `www.domain.com/design` to `domain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The reason why _your_ code doesn't work is that when in the .htaccess file in the `design` subdirectory, the `$1` backreference will be the empty string, so you end up back at the document root. If you simply moved it to the .htaccess file in your document root (above the WordPress directives) then it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the www before any url using this script in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: thank you, is it ok if i add it to .htaccess file in design folder? or it's better to add it to root .htaccess?

Comment: If you place it in the .htaccess inside the root of your server, it will take effect for all files, until another .htaccess changes that.

Comment: thanks alot, but another thing, i used that code and it's working all right but only when i'm using firefox(i tested the code i find with firefox) when i go to "www.domain.com/design" it still redirects to "domain.com" is it because of some sort of cache? or it's a problem?

Comment: Restart browser, try hitting F5 a few times, maybe restart your pc. Should work.

Comment: Good luck with your project.